# transcode function fails to convert hebrew string

Tags: xerces

I have two machines with the same local page setting.
On one machine the `transcode` function converts Hebrew strings and on the other machine it returns an empty string when converting.

Any ideas?

Comment: We need more detail.  I would first speculate what the LOCALE settings are for each machine.

Comment: This could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749417/xerces-xmlstringtranscode-null-empty-reply