# Xerces XMLString::transcode null/empty reply

Tags: locale, xerces, transcode

Xerces transcode is returning an empty string. I think it is related to locale issues, but i'm stuck.

I have this simple program:

```
#include <xercesc/util/PlatformUtils.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOM.hpp>
#include <xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp>
#include <xercesc/framework/MemBufInputSource.hpp>
#include <xercesc/dom/DOMException.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

XERCES_CPP_NAMESPACE_USE
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 string a = "Não";
 try
 {
   XMLPlatformUtils::Initialize("pt_PT");
 } catch(const XMLException& e)
 {
   fprintf(stdout,"ERROR INITIALIZING\n");
 }
 XMLCh *auxCh3 = XMLString::transcode(a.c_str());
 fprintf(stdout,"### %s ###\n",XMLString::transcode(auxCh3));
 XMLString::release(&auxCh3);
 XMLPlatformUtils::Terminate();
 return 0;
}
```

And the result is:

"###  ###"

If i remove the ã, the result is ok:

"### No ###"

The server's locale is defined to:

```
[]$ locale
LANG=pt_PT
LC_CTYPE="pt_PT"
LC_NUMERIC="pt_PT"
```

Which is one of the available:

```
[]$ locale -a|grep pt_PT
pt_PT
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When your program starts, by default it is in "C" locale. This is defined by POSIX standard. You need to call `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")` (don't forget to `#include <locale.h>` ) , to set the locale according to system environment variables.